# Use a class object inside of another class? or just use fields?

Tags: class, oop, inheritance

I am practicing OOP Inheritance and came across a question, which I have a few ideas on an answer to, but I am not sure what is the "correct" way of thinking.

Say you have a class for a Person. That person has a name. Would you create a class for Name, then make an object of it inside of Person? Or would you just use fields for the first and last name?

Personally, I think that if it doesn't manipulate the data or isn't a lot of data - then I may as well just create 2 fields for first and last name at the class at the top of the inheritance tree so it will be inherited by all the sub classes.

Am I thinking about that correctly?

Thanks :D

Bryan

Comment: In some cultures people might only have 1 name. Or have a middle name. Or 4 names... So in this case, it might be better to create a `Name` class

Comment: So it's more circumstance based than an exact principal everytime? Good to know. Thanks :)

Comment: See _the myths programmers believe about names_.

Comment: See the developer answer. A good example for a separated class is an Address (several attributes). A name can be a single FullName, but also a name composed of FirstName, LastName, MiddleNames, and you may want it in separate Object (or not).

Answer (score 1):

The Way I and I think the most people handle this is by atomic attributes. So if the attribute you want to assign to the Object is complex (mostly having multiple attributes) or if it is clearly a thing in our world, we would create an object for it. If it's an atomic attribute or with no direct link to another attribute, it's fine to stay within the main object.